# WHM/cPanel Copy Multiple Accounts/Packages From Another Server failing for each account?

Tags: centos, cpanel, centos6, whm

Just bought a new server that runs WHM/cPanel, same as the old. Trying to use the built in tool to migrate multiple accounts / packages over. I'm able to connect to the other server, it lists out all the packages & accounts, I select all and start the process.

Then it goes through each package and account and fails to copy anything over. This is the error given for a sample account:

Command failed with exit status 255

```
...etc...
Copying Suspension Info (if needed)...Done
Copying SSL certificates, CSRs, and keys...Privilege de-escalation before loading    datastore either failed or was omitted. at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/SSLStorage.pm line 1159
Cpanel::SSLStorage::_load_datastore('Cpanel::SSLStorage::Installed=HASH(0x3c72300)',     'lock', 1) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/SSLStorage.pm line 1244
       Cpanel::SSLStorage::_load_datastore_rw('Cpanel::SSLStorage::Installed=HASH(0x3c72300)')     called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/SSLStorage/Installed.pm line 634
       Cpanel::SSLStorage::Installed::_rebuild_records('Cpanel::SSLStorage::Installed=HASH(0x3c7230    0)') called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/SSLStorage.pm line 308
    Cpanel::SSLStorage::__ANON__() called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/SSLStorage.pm line     1330
        Cpanel::SSLStorage::_execute_coderef('Cpanel::SSLStorage::Installed=HASH(0x3c72300)',     'CODE(0x49ee958)') called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/SSLStorage.pm line 310
    Cpanel::SSLStorage::rebuild_records('Cpanel::SSLStorage::Installed=HASH(0x3c72300)')     called at /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/pkgacct line 2888
    Script::Pkgacct::__ANON__('Cpanel::SSLStorage::Installed=HASH(0x3c72300)') called at     /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/pkgacct line 2913
    Script::Pkgacct::backup_ssl_for_user('jshea89', '/home/webwizard/cpmove-jshea89')     called at /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/pkgacct line 532
    Script::Pkgacct::script('Script::Pkgacct', '--use_backups', '--skiphomedir',      'jshea89', '/home/webwizard', '--split', '--compressed', '--mysql', 5.5, ...) called at      /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/pkgacct line 111

==sshcontroloutput==
sh-4.1# exit $RET
exit
sh-4.1$ exit $RET
exit

sshcommandfailed=255`
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a hack, but I went to /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/SSLStorage.pm line 1244 and commented out the Carp.

Accounts from my old dead server are now archiving :)

Answer (score 0):

After some researching, I was able to determine that this was caused by incorrect ownership on the */home/user/ssl* directory and its subdirectories. Someone had set the owner and group to *root:root*, when infact it should have been *user:user*.

Hopefully this helps some of you solve the problem!